# impact about upgrade redmine from 0.96 to 1.2.1

Tags: redmine

the redmine server that we used in out project does updated for a long time.
the version of redmine that we used is 0.96.
for now i wanted to upgrade it to the newest version(1.2.1).
It's there any impact about that?

Answer (score 1):

Of course there's an **impact to upgrading** - you'll get **new features**, and lots of **bug fixes**, and probably some **new bugs** to fix in future versions.

I think the **list of implemented features** on the roadmap of redmine.org answers this question best:
[http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/roadmap?tracker_ids[]=2&completed=1](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/roadmap?tracker_ids%5B%5D=2&completed=1)

There may be some plugins that won't work anymore or need upgrading.

Other than that, just be sure to make a backup of your database before upgrading.